# How to stretch entry widget

Tags: go, fyne

I have a problem with proper layout of widgets.

**What I Have:**
[image]

**What I Want:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
  grid := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewGridLayout(5), newSpacer, newSpacer, newSpacer, topRSpace, topC)

  // Group of files and dirs buttons
  fileBox := widget.NewVBox(files...)
  dirBox := widget.NewVBox(dirs...)

  entryDisabled := widget.NewMultiLineEntry()
  entryDisabled.SetText("Disabled")
  entryDisabled.Disable()
  entryBox := widget.NewVBox(entryDisabled)

  group := widget.NewGroup(so.GetPath(),dirBox, fileBox)

  container1 := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewBorderLayout(group, nil, nil, nil), group, entryBox)
  
  group2 :=  widget.NewVScrollContainer(container1)

  container2 := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewBorderLayout(grid, nil, nil, nil), grid, group2)
  mainWindow.SetContent(container2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured that out. The NewVBox around entryDisabled need to be removed.